# Magento2 - Wait for checkout page completely loaded and fire JS code

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, javascript, knockoutjs, requirejs

The goal is to add a piece of JS to manipulate a date picker on the checkout page. I use an OSC (OneStepCheckout from mageplaza). So far I've followed [this documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html) and added this mixin:

```
var config = {
  config: {
    mixins: {
      'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information': {
        'Vendor_Module/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin': true
      },
    }
  }
}
```

in this file:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'mage/utils/wrapper',
], function ($, wrapper) {
  'use strict';

  // the html is not there so this is empty
  var datepicker = $('#datepicker')

  return function (setShippingInformationAction) {
    return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction) {

      // ... some custom code ... //
      return originalAction();
    });
  };
});
```

When I load the page the date picker var has no HTMLElements, the reason is that the checkout is loading all the checkout components. So how can I tell the mixin to wait until the checkout components are completely done/loaded?

Maybe it shouldn't be a mixin?

Answer (score 2):

Try using like below

```
require([
'jquery',
'Magento_Ui/js/lib/view/utils/dom-observer',
], function ($,$do) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $do.get('.class-name', function(elem){
            $(elem).addClass('test-class');
            //your code
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This works for me, +1.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the DOM to be ready with this `!domReady` requireJs utility.

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'mage/utils/wrapper',
  '!domReady'
], function ($, wrapper) {
  'use strict';

  var datepicker = $('#datepicker')

  return function (setShippingInformationAction) {
    return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction) {

      // ... some custom code ... //
      return originalAction();
    });
  };
});
```

However due to knockout templates loading asynchronously via knockout this may not work.

I would try initializing `datepicker` in the wrapper itself. Something like so:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'mage/utils/wrapper',
  '!domReady'
], function ($, wrapper) {
  'use strict';

  var datePickerFunc = function() {
       var datepicker = $('#datepicker');
       ...do datepicker things....

  };

  return function (setShippingInformationAction) {
    return wrapper.wrap(setShippingInformationAction, function (originalAction) {
       datePickerFunc();
      // ... some custom code ... //
      return originalAction();
    });
  };
});
```

None of this is tested.

Comment: Sadly this didn't work :(

Comment: The mixin is working (as far as I can tell). I placed the console logs in both functions but only the `return function (setShippingInformationAction)` logs something. But I think that is correct because the `setShippingInformationAction` isn't triggered yet.

Comment: Maybe this mixin isn't the right place? Maybe it shouldn't be in a action but model or something else perhaps?

Comment: This is the full source. What more should I provide?

Comment: @Katch Did you find any solution for this ?